# How to use markdown for description from a file in gitlab CI using release API

Tags: api, continuous-integration, gitlab, markdown, release

I'm using the Gitlab release API in the gitlab-ci.yml to be able to automatically create a new release when deploying.

Simply putting a curl request like [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/#create-a-release) in the docs works just fine. For the description, the docs state that markdown is allowed, which is great. However, I can't seem to figure out or come up with an idea to load a description from a markdown file within the curl request. I've already tried storing the content of the markdown file in a variable in the gitlab-ci.yml prior to the curl and then pass it and expand it within the curl like so:

```
# gitlab-ci.yml
...
- DESCRIPTION=`cat ./description.md`
```

and also to just put the `cat ./description.md` in the curl request itself as the value of "description".

Here is the example from the docs:

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: gDybLx3yrUK_HLp3qPjS" \
     --data '{ "name": "New release", "tag_name": "v0.3", "description": "Super nice release", "milestones": ["v1.0", "v1.0-rc"], "assets": { "links": [{ "name": "hoge", "url": "https://google.com" }] } }' \
     --request POST https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/24/releases
```

And for the "description" key I would like to pass the contents of a markdown file as the value.

I was surprised to not have found a post or discussion about this already, so I suspect I'm either missing something (very basic/obvious) or folks don't really use this function (yet)?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the variable like you, this `.gitlab-ci.yml` works :

```
create_release:
    script:
      - DESCRIPTION=$(cat description.md)
      - |
        curl --silent --request POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" \ 
        --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: TOKEN" \ 
        --data '{"name":"New release","tag_name":"v0.3", "description":"'"$DESCRIPTION"'","assets":{"links":[{"name":"hoge","url":"https://google.com"}]}}' \
        https://gitlab.bankassembly.com/api/v4/projects/369/releases
```

The variable is expanded inside double quote (see https://superuser.com/a/835589)

Example of the content of my `description.md` :

```
## CHANGELOG\r\n\r\n- Escape label and milestone titles to prevent XSS in GFM autocomplete. !2740\r\n- Prevent private snippets from being embeddable.\r\n- Add subresources removal to member destroy service.
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll give that a try again!

Comment: Thanks again for the help. It actually turns out that for some reason I yet have to figure out it wasn't the curl api call but:
`
- DESCRIPTION=$(cat description.md)
`
this line, or rather something funky going on with the `cat` command. I tried echoing the contents of DESCRIPTION after defining it as a variable like suggested and it get the first line of the file i specified and then the contents of ls ./
I then also tried to reinstall coreutils (of which cat is part) for the alpine image I use prior to the cat call without luck

Comment: So, when I save markdown simply as a string in DESCRIPTION it works e.g.:

`DESCRIPTION="## CHANGELOG\r\n\r\n- Escape label and milestone titles to ..."`