# Storing markdown in variable using cat from a file to be expanded in api call in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm (now) successfully using the Gitlab's release api to trigger a release on a repo. However, I discovered that passing markdown from a string variable into the curl to the api works just fine. When using `cat` to get markdown from a file i cannot get the variable to expand properly. The pipeline succeeds anyway, but without making the API call.

I've tried following the official suggestion from the docs that had been suggested in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58689814/how-to-use-markdown-for-description-from-a-file-in-gitlab-ci-using-release-api/58696368#58696368). I've also tried several other things like using a script instead specifying bash and zsh as the shell as the default is just sh in my gitlab docker.

```
create_release:
    script:
      - DESCRIPTION=$(cat description.md)
      - |
        curl --silent --request POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" \ 
        --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: TOKEN" \ 
        --data '{"name":"New release","tag_name":"v0.3", "description":"'"$DESCRIPTION"'","assets":{"links":[{"name":"hoge","url":"https://google.com"}]}}' \
        https://gitlab.bankassembly.com/api/v4/projects/369/releases
```

It works a s expected when I just put some markdown as a string like `DESCRIPTION="## Changelog \r\n something something ..."`, but no matter what I tried it doesn't quite work when using `DESCRIPTION=$(cat description.md)`

Comment: What does it mean  when you say "it does not quiet work"? Try using this: `DESCRIPTION="$(<description.md)"`

Comment: It meant that whatever I tried I didn't get it to correctly store the contents of the markdown in the variable, sometimes incorrectly, sometimes not at all, sometimes not expanding it correctly. I've tried anything I could come up with that's why I didn't post all the variants here.

Comment: However, the problem is solved now by moving the script to an actual script file `tagrelease.sh` that declares to use bash as a shell and then run it in the yaml file with 
```yaml
script:
   - ...
   - tagrelease.sh
```